# Structure object for vuejs autocomplete in laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out why my autocomplete isn't showing options properly. First of all, I'm sending this hard coded data from my controller upon axios call:

searchController.php

```
$searchResults = [
        0 => (object) [
            'title' => '123',
            'description' => 'testing',
        ],
        1 => (object) [
            'title' => 'New one',
            'description' => 'testing',
        ],
        2 => (object) [
            'title' => 'One More',
            'description' => 'testing',
        ],
    ];

    return json_encode($searchResults);
```

I'm taking that response and setting it to my `item` value in vue. Then in the template I'm accessing `item.title` but it's just showing the entire block as one item like

```
[
        0 => (object) [
            'title' => '123',
            'description' => 'testing',
        ],
        1 => (object) [
            'title' => 'New one',
            'description' => 'testing',
        ],
        2 => (object) [
            'title' => 'One More',
            'description' => 'testing',
        ],
    ]
```

Rest of the code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <autocomplete :items="items" v-model="item" :get-label="getLabel" :component-item='template' @update-items="getSearch">
        </autocomplete>
        <div style="background-color: white;">
        <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Autocomplete from 'v-autocomplete';
import 'v-autocomplete/dist/v-autocomplete.css';

Vue.component('autocomplete', Autocomplete);

export default {
  data () {
        return {
            item: [],
            items: [],
        }
  },
  methods: {
    getLabel (item) {
      return item.name
    },
    getSearch() {
      axios.get('/search')
      .then(response => {

        this.item = response.data;
        console.info(this.item);

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        this.loading = false;
        // handle error
        console.log(error)
      })
      .finally(function() {
        this.loading = false;
      })
    },

  }
};
</script>
```

How can I structure this differently so that each object is one item where I can access the separate title and description in my template?

Answer (score 0):

In your `SearchController` method, simply change this:

```
return json_encode($searchResults);
```

with this:

```
return response()->json($searchResults);
```